# Terminal Command To Find What Version Of Git I Have Installed?

Tags: git, terminal

What is the terminal command to find the version of Git currently installed on my system?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yeah, simple - `git --version` (holds true for most applications)

---

If you get `-bash: git: command not found` when you run `git --version` it means git is not installed or it is not on PATH.

1. Make sure git is installed.

   - Git is usually installed at `/usr/local/git/`
   - Make sure there is a binary file where you installed git. If not, [install git.](http://git-scm.com/)
2. If git is installed, then it is mostly likely not on PATH

   - Find the path where you installed it and do something like this to add it to the path and set in your profile:

     `echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`
   - Then make sure you restart terminal before trying to run any git commands

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought. When I try that I get "-bash: git: command not found" I know git is installed. Been using it for some time now. I am in my users directory if that matters.

Comment: @zechdc - If you get command not found, either it is not installed, or it is not on PATH.

Comment: @Radu It is installed. At least I believe it is installed. I just committed something using Tower App.

Comment: @zechdc - Find where you installed and do something like `echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`

Comment: @manojlds Ok, it looks like git is installed at `/usr/local/git`. I ran that command and it created a file called .profile in my user directory. Still can't run `git --version` Is there more to it than just run that command? I am kinda a terminal newb. :)

Comment: @zechdc - Make sure that folder - `/usr/local/git` does have a `git` binary file.

Comment: @manojlds There is a "Unix Executable File" called "git" located at /usr/local/git/bin/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4346/discussion-between-zechdc-and-manojlds)